# What is the need for an unsaved-value attribute in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

What is the need for an `unsaved-value` attribute?

```
<id name="userid" column="userid" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="null">   
  <generator class="sequence">
    <param name="sequence">dmuseridseq</param>
  </generator> 
</id>
```

Answer (score 15):

It is explained in [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20061016065626/http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html) brilliant article:

> The Hibernate mapping file indicates that the id field on Person is
>   the database ID (i.e. it is the primary key in the PERSON table).
>   Within the id tag is an attribute, unsaved-value="null", that tells
>   Hibernate to use the id field to determine whether a Person object has
>   been previously saved or not. ORM frameworks must make this
>   distinction to know whether they should save the object with a SQL
>   INSERT or UPDATE statement. In this case, Hibernate assumes that the
>   id field starts out null on new objects and is assigned when they are
>   first saved.

Also, you can read about "unsaved-value" in the book "Java Persistence with Hibernate":

[image]

Answer (score 6):

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html

> unsaved-value (optional - defaults to a "sensible" value): an identifier property value that indicates an instance is newly instantiated (unsaved), distinguishing it from detached instances that were saved or loaded in a previous session.

In your example, `unsaved-value="null"` seems pretty pointless, since I suspect the "sensible default" for a `Long` is `null`.

It's more useful for primitive types (e.g. `int`), which cannot be `null`, and the default unsaved-value of `0` may be undesirable in some applications (`0` being a perfectly valid number value).

Comment: who and when sets this unsaved value? could you pleasd give an example?